# Split a read list into its elements

Tags: clips, jess

I want to get a person allergies and then split allergy by allergy to assert each one. To do this I use the `do-backward-chaining`, `assert-string` and `readline`.

```
(do-backward-chaining allergies)

(defrule ask-allergies
    (need-allergies nil)
    =>
    (printout t "Tell me your allergies (tomato, cheese): ")
    (assert-string (str-cat "(allergies " (readline) ")")))

(defrule assert-allergies
    (allergies $? ?a $?)
    =>
    (assert (allergy ?a)))

(reset)
(run)
```

But outputs this error:

```
Jess reported an error in routine Context.getVariable
    while executing (reset).
Message: No such variable _blank_mf1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any detailed documentation on how the backward chaining works, but I think you need to use $?variables where you just have $? in the assert-allergies pattern:

```
Jess> (do-backward-chaining allergies)
TRUE
Jess> 
(defrule ask-allergies
    (need-allergies $?)
    =>
    (printout t "Tell me your allergies (tomato, cheese): ")
    (assert-string (str-cat "(allergies " (readline) ")")))
TRUE
Jess> 
(defrule assert-allergies
    (allergies $?b ?a $?e)
    =>
    (assert (allergy ?a)))
TRUE
Jess> (reset)
TRUE
Jess> (run)
Tell me your allergies (tomato, cheese): fish onions salt
4
Jess> (facts)
f-0   (MAIN::initial-fact)
f-1   (MAIN::need-allergies nil nil nil)
f-2   (MAIN::allergies fish onions salt)
f-3   (MAIN::allergy salt)
f-4   (MAIN::allergy fish)
f-5   (MAIN::allergy onions)
For a total of 6 facts in module MAIN.
Jess>
```